# Changing value of integer mapped with h:outputText using jquery in jsf 2.0

Tags: jquery, jsf-2, web

i had mapped an Integer to h:outputText (JSF 2.0)

```
<h:outputText id="txt_pay_days" value="#{articleBean.noOfDays}"/>
```

and changed the value using jquery using

```
$("#txt_pay_days").text("123");
```

the value of integer is not changed to 123 in the bean (on the server side) .

What am i doing wrong. Or is this not the right way to do it.

Any suggestions ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to change on server side you need an ajax call.
You can use f:ajax

```
<h:commandButton value="My ajax button">
    <f:setPropertyActionListener target="#{articleBean.noOfDays}" value="123" />
    <f:ajax  execute="txt_pay_days" update="txt_pay_days" />
</h:commandButton>
```

Execute tell which component(s) you want to process in ajax call , and update tell wich component(s) you want to update in view.

setPropertyActionListener will set the value of #{articleBean.noOfDays} .

You can found more informantion [here](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/pdldocs/facelets/f/ajax.html):

Comment: It is an `h:outputText` that won't go to the server.

Comment: Matt, i know it's an outputText, this button it's just an example, when clicked will update the outputText.

Comment: But the client side change doesn't get to the server thus you will get the "old" value from server again.